# Accessing XML tags with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

This is the xml im using. i am trying to access the planet tag and print it to a page. However when I print it,  it grabs the first instance of  and then in satellite it grabs the second.  Is there a way to select only the first instance of ?

```
 <PLANET COLOR="BLUE">
        <NAME>Earth</NAME>
        <DISTANCE UNITS="km">149.60</DISTANCE>
        <RADIUS UNITS="km">6371</RADIUS>
            <SATELLITE>
               <NAME>Moon</NAME>
               <DISTANCE_FROM_PLANET>384405</DISTANCE_FROM_PLANET>
               <ORBIT UNITS="days">27.322</ORBIT>
            </SATELLITE>
    </PLANET>

function getData(){
       $.ajax({

         url: 'Planets.xml',
         dataType: 'xml',
         success: function(data){

            $(data).find("PLANET").each(function(){

                pInfo = '</br><li>Name:  ' +$(this).find("NAME").text() +'</li><li>Distance:  '+$(this).find("DISTANCE").text() +'</li><li>Radius:   ' +$(this).find("RADIUS").text() +'</li></br>';

                $("#p").append(pInfo);

            });
```

When I append pInfo to the div "p" it prints out the name of the planet and the name of the satellite.  Is there any way I can just select the first  tag instead of grabbing the one from satellite along with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method loops through all the `PLANET`s. You can get the first `PLANET` by using [**.first()**](https://api.jquery.com/first/) as follows:

```
 var pFirst = $(data).find("PLANET").first(),
 pInfo = '</br><li>Name: ' + pFirst.children("NAME").first().text() + '</li><li>Distance:  ' + pFirst.find("DISTANCE").text() + '</li><li>Radius:   ' + pFirst.find("RADIUS").text() + '</li></br>';
 $("#p").append(pInfo);
```

**UPDATE**

Turns out the question was about `$(this).find('NAME').text()` returning `EarthMoon` instead of `Earth`. The best approach would be to use `.children('NAME').text()` or:

```
$(this).find('>NAME').text() //Not the >
```

Comment: I want all the planets, however the tag inside of planet <satellite> contains the <name> also.  I want the name from planet not satellite.

Comment: I see what you mean. You can either use `.first().text()` or `.children('NAME').first().text()`

Comment: +$(this).find("NAME").first().text() worked!  Thank you so much +1